# Correct way to use librosa mfcc with Random Forest

Tags: random-forest, librosa, mfcc

I would like to know what is the best approach in order to use librosa.feature.mfcc feature extraction in a Random Forest classifier?

2 cases is as follows:

Case 1:

I have 1000 audio files and use the librosa mfcc feature extraction as is:

```
def extract_features(file_name):
    try:
        durationSeconds = 1
        audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
        trimmed = librosa.util.fix_length(audio, size=int(sample_rate * durationSeconds))
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=trimmed, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
        pad_width = max_pad_len - mfccs.shape[1]
        mfccs = np.pad(mfccs, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')

except Exception as e:
    print("Error encountered while parsing file: ", file_name)
    return None

return mfccs
```

I would then flatten the 3D array generated by this feature extraction via:

```
X_train_flat = np.array([features_2d.flatten() for features_2d in X_train])
```

and then send this to the Random Forest classifier.

Case 2:

For the same 1000 audio files, I use:

```
def extract_features(file_name):
    try:
        durationSeconds = 1
        audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
        trimmed = librosa.util.fix_length(audio, size=int(sample_rate * durationSeconds))
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=trimmed, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
        pd.Series(np.hstack((np.mean( mfccs, axis=1), np.std( mfccs, axis=1))))   #returns mfcc features with mean and standard deviation along time

except Exception as e:
    print("Error encountered while parsing file: ", file_name)
    return None

return  pd.Series([0]*40)
```

I would then pass this X_train data to the Random Forest Classifier.

```
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Note that in the first use case, when I flatten the data, I get X_train of size 1000 x 6920.  This, in effect, have me parsing 6920 features to the Random Forest classifier for analysis compared to the 2nd use case of 40.

Can you tell me which approach is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the classification task you are solving? Either approach can be used. Also one can do intermediate versions, by processing shorter segments of audio/MFCCs, and merged on output

Comment: Thanks!  The task is to classify different urban sounds.  To train the model to tell if the sound is a car, train, footsteps,  person talking.

Comment: @JonNordby, can you post a solution incorporating  your comment but using Case 2?